# which we had been doing for the last three weeks

Tags: meaning, which

a. They suggested that we contact each other via the net once every two months, which was what we had been doing in the last three weeks.

b. They suggested that once every two months we contact each other via the net, which was what we had been doing in the last three weeks.

c. They suggested that we contact each other via the net once every two months. We had been doing that in the last three weeks.

d. They suggested that once every two months we contact each other via the net. We had been doing that in the last three weeks.

The sentences are grammatical, but do they make sense?

The idea is: We had been contacting each other via the net for three weeks. After  that, they suggested that we contact each other once every two months.

I think (a) is saying that 'we had been contacting each other once every two months for the last three weeks' and that is absurd. I am not sure the other ones work either,

Obviously common sense would rule out that interpretation so maybe (a) works.

Many thanks

Comment: This is a request for proofreading, which is off-topic for this site, so I have closed the question to new answers. If you are uncertain about some specific aspect of English, then please ask about that, but do not simply post several of your best guesses and ask if they're correct.

Answer (score 1):

I’m a native speaker and I could not work out how you two could be doing anything “every two months”, for three week.

The opposite, doing something every three week for two months, makes sense — you would have done it three or four times — but if it had a two-month cycle...

You mean, as you have been doing for the last three weeks, perhaps daily, you want to continue doing, but only on a bi-monthly schedule.

(b) comes the closest to making that clear, but it’s still vague.

How about “We had been contacting each other via the net over the last three weeks.  They suggested that we do so once every two months.”